Is the Jacobian map a ring homomorphism?
Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Consider the ring of formal power series $A=R[[x]]$ and $B=(R[[x,y]])^2$, the later one is the direct product of the ring $R[[x,y]]$.
Let us consider the corresponding ring of endomorphisms $\text{End}_R(A)$ and $\text{End}_R(B)$, which are of course $R$-modules.
The derivative map $D: \text{End}_R(A) \to R$ defined by $D(f(x))=\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)|_{x=0})=f'(0)$ is a ring homomorphism.
Let us define the Jacobian map $J: \text{End}_R(B) \to R^4$ by
$$J_f=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{f_1(x,y)}{\partial x}(0,0) & \frac{f_1(x,y)}{\partial y}(0,0) \\
\frac{f_2(x,y)}{\partial x}(0,0) & \frac{f_2(x,y)}{\partial y}(0,0) \end{bmatrix}$$
for all $ f(x,y)=(f_1(x,y), f_2(x,y)) \in \text{End}_R(B) $.
There is no problem with $J_{f+g}=J_f+J_g$ for all $f,g \in \text{End}_R(B)$, as Jacobian is a linear map.
Since the multiplication operation in $\text{End}_R(B)$ is given by the composition map, we have to show at $(0,0)$
$$J_{f \circ g}=J_f \cdot J_g.$$
But by the formula of Jacobian for composite function, the left hand side of the above equation becomes
$J_{f \circ g}=J_f(g(x,y)) \cdot J_g$.
So it seems the above jacobian map $J$ is not a ring homomorphism.
Am I correct?

Could you include an example, where $J(f\cdot g)\neq J(f)\cdot J(g)$? Then it should be clear.

You speak of rings and their endomorphism rings, but that doesn't make sense (ring endomorphisms don't constitute a ring). Also your notation $End_R$ suggests that you consider $R$-modules and their endomorphism rings? Please clarify (in the post).

@MartinBrandenburg, Yes, you are right. I have clarified the post. I am considering $R$-modules.

So are you saying that $g(x,y)=(x ,y)$?

@TedShifrin, thanks. You are right. I was careless. There are many $g(x,y)$, for which the left side is not equal to right side. The upshot is that the above Jacobian map will not be a ring endomorphism
